# How to parameterize table name in Slick

Tags: scala, slick

```
class MyTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[MyEntity](tag, "1970Table") {
  def id = column[Int]("id")

  override def * = 
  (
   id
  ) <> (MyEntity.tupled, MyEntity.unapply)
}

val myTable = TableQuery[MyTable]

class MyRepository(val config: DatabaseConfig[JdbcProfile])
   extends MyRepository[MyTable, String] {
  override val table: config.profile.api.TableQuery[MyTable] = myTable

  def insert(me: MyEntity): Future[Int] = {
     db.run(table += me)
  }
}
```

I use this in my other classes like this:

```
  val myRepository = new MyRepository(dbConfig)

  myRepository.insert(myrecord)
```

**Question**

I would like to not have a hardcoded tablename but rather make the tablename dynamic.

I would like to change the `insert` method such that it accepts a `year (int)` parameter and based on the year parameter it chooses the right table. i.e. if the year passed in is `1970` then table name is `1970Table` but if the year passed in is `1980` then the table is `1980Table`.

Comment: did you try to add one more parameter to `MyTable` class like `name` and pass it further to Slick Table. Then create one more variable for 1980Table in  `MyRepository ` and choose which one to use in insert method?

Comment: the `table` variable in `MyRepository` is overriding the `table` variable. So I'm unable to add more than one `table` variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
class MyRepository(val config: DatabaseConfig[JdbcProfile]) {
  import config._
  import profile.api._

  abstract class MyTable(tag: Tag, name: String) extends Table[MyEntity](tag, name) {
    def id = column[Int]("id")
    override def * = (id) <> (MyEntity.tupled, MyEntity.unapply)
  }

  class Table1970(tag: Tag) extends MyTable[MyEntity](tag, "1970Table")
  class Table1980(tag: Tag) extends MyTable[MyEntity](tag, "1980Table")

  val table1970 = TableQuery[Table1970]
  val table1980 = TableQuery[Table1980]

  def insert(me: MyEntity, year: Int): Future[Int] = db.run {
    year match {
      case "1970" => table1970 += me
      case "1980" => table1980 += me 
    }
  }
}
```

Now

```
val myRepository = new MyRepository(dbConfig)
myRepository.insert(myrecord, "1970")
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what `Table1970` and `Table1980` refer to in your answer...Not able to understand where they fit in the example in the question. Thanks

Comment: The concern I have with this approach is that it will require me to copy paste the code for each `Table1970`, `Table1978`, etc class I'll be making Because the insert/delete/etc methods are same for each year. Only thing changing is the tablename.

Answer (score 0):

There is two `apply` methods in TableQuery. `val myTable = TableQuery[MyTable]` -
this one uses macros to create `MyTable`.
The other one is defined like this:

```
def apply[E <: AbstractTable[_]](cons: Tag => E): TableQuery[E] =
    new TableQuery[E](cons)
```

So you can do smth like this

```
class MyTable(tag: Tag, tableName: String) extends Table[MyEntity](tag, tableName)
...
def myTable(name: String) = TableQuery[MyTable](tag =>  new MyTable(tag, name))
```

Now you can predefine all tables you need and use them or do smth like this

```
class MyRepository(val config: DatabaseConfig[JdbcProfile])
   extends MyRepository[MyTable, String] {
  override def table(year: Int): config.profile.api.TableQuery[MyTable] = myTable(year.toString)

  def insert(me: MyEntity, year: Int): Future[Int] = {
     db.run(table(year) += me)
  }
}
```